# How to change the image source inside Wordpress Posts when an image is expired

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

As mentioned in the title. I try to change the image source to a default image, if an image's expiration date is expired.

I used ACF and added a new date field to all media files.

I then created the following function:

```
 function check_expiration_date($post) {
  $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);
  $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
  $today = date('d/m/Y');
  $expire = get_field('expiration_date', $thumbnail_id);
  if( $expire < $today && $expire!="" )
  {
    $url = "default.jpg";
  }
  return $url;
}
```

Now this function works for images that I add sepcifically in template files
but this will not work for images that have been added via the editor on post pages.

I tried to to use various hooks to change the html markup first before attempting to get the meta information but none of those had any effect on the outcome. Here an example:

```
 function change_image_markup($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url) {
  $html5 = "<section>";
  $html5 .= "<figure id='post-$id media-$id' class='align-$align'>";
  $html5 .= "<img src='$url' alt='$title' />";
  if ($caption) {
    $html5 .= "<figcaption>$caption</figcaption>";
  }
  $html5 .= "</figure>";
  $html5 .= "<section>";
  return $html5;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'change_image_markup', 10, 9 );
```

Is there a specific hook that can alter the html markup of images?

I am using Wordpress 5.5.1
any hint or tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question is a month old and I did not receive any answers, I figured I would answer my own question. There is a difference in the requirements though. Instead of changing the image to a default one, I removed the image completely. Both can be achieved though.

So there was no real hook that could me out, as those hooks only call the action when actually inserting the image.
In my case everytime the post is being loaded the images had to be checked if they are expired or not.

Instead of working with hooks I created my own function and call that function inside single.php

In the single.php usually there is something like echo post->post_content;
Instead I call my function and give the post content as a value.

```
add_post_based_on_expiration_date($post->post_content);
```

And my function looks something like this:

```
function add_post_based_on_expiration_date($post_content){
  $search_pattern = '/<figure(.*)\/figure>/'; //<figure(.*)/figure>   /wp-image-(\d+)/
  preg_match_all( $search_pattern, $post_content, $embedded_images );
  $embedded_images_count = count( $embedded_images[0] );
  $new_content = $post_content;
  if ( $embedded_images_count > 0 ) {
       for ( $i=0; $i < $embedded_images_count ; $i++ ) {
            $dom = new DOMDocument;
            @$dom->loadHTML($embedded_images[0][$i]);
            $image = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
            $imageId = str_replace("wp-image-" , "" , $image[0]->getAttribute('class'));
            if(check_expiration_date_get_by_id($imageId)){
              $new_content = str_replace($embedded_images[0][$i],"",$new_content);
            }

       };
  };
  echo $new_content;
}
```

It looks a bit messy but it does it's job. What I do is using regex to look for the image mark up <figure..... and save it in an array. Afterwards by using the DOM class I get the class, which contains the media ID. Then I call my function which is an alteration of the one above in the question. The function just returns true or false depeding on the expiration date. If it is true I remove it from the content and at the end I return it.

Therefore if an image is expired the image markup gets completely removed.
The downside of this aside from the messy code is the processing time. Since it it always called when opening a post site.